# GridView rows jumping around while editing data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, active-directory

I've got a simple intranet form (ASP.NET 2.0) with a GridView bound to data from Active Directory. It does this with an SqlDataSource that selects from a view that pulls the data from AD. This works better than doing LDAP queries directly from ASP.NET, since I can do table joins, etc. without much fuss. The GridView has a CommandField column with an edit button, and a few EditItemTemplates with DropDownLists for selecting valid values.

Updates, on the other hand, *are* done by connecting directly to AD. To allow for this, I have to handle the OnRowUpdating event of the GridView, and set Cancel in the GridViewUpdateEventArgs to true, since the SqlDataSource has no update command defined. Then it just creates a DirectorySearcher, looks up the user based on distinguishedName (the data key of the GridView), calls GetDirectoryEntry() on the result, sets a couple properties, and finally calls CommitChanges() on the DirectoryEntry. No problems there - it's updating the data just fine.

It *is*, however, behaving a little confusingly. It seems there's a bit of a propagation delay when updating the data. It takes roughly ten seconds after updating before the view used for the SqlDataSource reflects the change. I'm not sure if this is typical AD behavior, or if the view is connecting to a different DC than the one the update is being issued against. This behavior isn't a problem in and of itself, and I can live with it if necessary.

But while that isn't a big problem, it's causing *another* issue - the GridView is sorted by default on the "company" column, which is one of the properties the user is allowed to edit. If the user changes the company on a row, waits a little while (or continues making multiple edits), then goes to edit another row, they could potentially end up editing a row adjacent to the one they wanted. This is because the GridView rebinds, and suddenly the row that had its company changed is sorted elsewhere in the list. The GridView is evidently triggering the edit based on the index of the row, and suddenly there's a different row at that index because the view used for the data source suddenly just caught up to reality.

What's sort of perplexing is that the GridView is trying to data bind on every post-back. In the past, I've had to make sure to call DataBind() after making data edits to ensure the data is up-to-date, but now it's happily hitting the data source every time. And yet the page ViewState is coming in around 66 KB, so I know the GridView is putting its data there.

So, off the top of my head, these would be a couple of fixes (that I haven't implemented successfully yet).

1. Stop the GridView from data binding with every page load, and stick with what it's got cached in ViewState. There's no "Cancel" property on the GridView's OnDataBinding event args, and setting Cancel during the data source's OnSelecting event just leaves me with an empty GridView.
2. Fix the propagation delay. Again, I don't have my heart set on that, but if it's a means of fixing the rows jumping around unexpectedly, then that's fine with me. Would I just have to make sure I'm explicitly connecting to the same DC both in the database view and when updating AD from ASP.NET? Or is there something more going on?
3. Trigger the row edit based on the primary key of the row rather than the index. I'm guessing I'd have to create a CommandButton in the row, set the CommandArgument to the primary key of the row, then walk through all the rows in the GridView on post-back and manually set EditIndex accordingly.

I'm open to other ideas too. If the ViewState ends up being a couple hundred KB, that's workable. This site is accessed over a pretty speedy LAN, and is strictly for internal use.

Comment: Have you considered not using a SqlDataSource at all and binding programmatically for the whole app?

Comment: I've considered it, but then I'll have to do a lot more legwork to handle the data binding, sorting, etc. It's not out of the question, but if there's a simpler fix, I'd prefer that obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Active Directory from ASP.NET tends to be a little slow no matter how you access it.

Not knowing what your code looks like, I would suggest the UpdatePanel and UpdateProgess tools if you are using the default ASP.NET tool set.

This will prevent any additional calls to the server until the update is complete. Something like this

```
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateMyGridViewProgress" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Updating the information" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateMyGridView" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView 
                ID="myGridView" 
                OnRowUpdating="UpdateAdInfo"
                runat="server" >
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've had to use something similar to this to help users understand when the update had completed in the past.

However, the default ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel tends to be verbose in the information that it posts back to the server for even simple operations.

Personally, I would try to avoid using GridView and use something a little more AJAX friendly (ie jqGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: Well, the thing is, the update request finishes nearly immediately, and the page loads shortly afterward, so I don't know how I could detect and wait for the delay short of just measuring a few runs, and putting in a sleep call with a best guess. But there's no point in slowing down the experience deliberately. I'm fine with there being a delay before the update actually takes, as long as I can find away around the goofy editing behavior when a row suddenly jumps somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent jumping around, you can use the **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack** property.

You can set this property to true in the Page directive of your ASPX page, like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>
```

Alternatively, you can set this property in the code-behind file of your ASPX page, in the Page_Load event handler, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Me.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True 
End Sub
```

Setting the **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack** property to true will keep the current scroll position of the page after a postback, such as when the user clicks the edit button in the GridView control. This will prevent the page from jumping to the top and provide a better user experience.